# Catalog of Categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, reference-works

Could someone please indicate a website, book or PDF that contains a catalog of categories? I am looking for a place that contains descriptions and properties of the best known categories. I am currently interested in the following categories:

- Category of Manifolds ($\mathbf{Man}$)
- Category of Smooth Manifolds ($\mathbf{Diff}$)
- Category of Topological Spaces ($\mathbf{Top}$)
- Category of Open Subsets of a topological space $X$ ($\mathbf{OpenSets}(X)$)
- Category of Algebras

I always have trouble finding a good description and properties of a certain category in which I am interested. That's why I'd like to know if there's a place that contains the descriptions and properties of the best known categories.

The best references I found are the following:

- [Categories in category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Categories_in_category_theory)
- [Database of Categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/database+of+categories)
- [Category Theory in Context](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf). On page 229 there is a catalog of categories. However, some categories in this catalog have only been cited briefly.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Are you familiar with the nlab?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I put in my question a link from the nlab site that describes several categories. But I would like to know if there are more complete references.

Comment: Huh - I didn't know they had a database of categories on their site. Sorry for the confusion, I assumed it was another site! In my comment I was thinking of the entire nlab as one database. If you're interested in concept X, then their page on that concept will almost surely contain some information about the category tied to concept X